# CakePHP won't read my default.po file

Tags: cakephp, localization

I've got a CakePHP application that works with multiple languages (on database level), and in the end, I generated a `.po` file with PoEdit and translated the keywords, but cake doesn't want to read it.

This is my code in *AppController*:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'mkd');

class AppController extends Controller {

  // ... some code here ...

  public function beforeFilter () {
      parent::beforeFilter();

      $this->params['language'] = 
                  !$this->params['language'] ? 'mkd' : $this->params['language'];
      Configure::write('Config.language', $this->params['language']);

  // more code...
  }
```

I know that declaring the language before AppController class is obsolete, but it was an act of desperation. Both parameters, `$this->params['language']` and `Configure::read('Config.language')`, are set to 'mkd', however it only displays the original values.

This is my localization folder structure:

- `C:\wamp\www\animalmedica\app\Locale\mkd\LC_MESSAGES\default.po`

I am using CakePHP 2.3. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does it work if you rename the `mkd` folder to `mk`?

Comment: No it doesn't, I tried that too. The funny thing is, I have it on another cake application like this (mkd), defined it only before the AppController class (like in this example, just without the beforeFilter function because for now it is only one language), and it works there. Blows my mind :)

Comment: Do you have `default.mo` in the same location as well?

Comment: agree with with Ip1051. And also, try to delete the cache files in app/tmp/cache folder and try.

Comment: I have the default.mo file. The problem was in the cache files. XuDing, can you write that as an answer so I can mark it? Thanks for your help guys.